# Best way to save/store customer purchase order data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-membership, e-commerce

I have a custom membership provider which I extended - added a couple of fields, first name, last name, adress, zip code and city.

now, these fields reside in the aspnet_Membership table so that I can easily access them when using the static Membership asp.net class.

now, I want to be able so save customer purchase order data (first name, last name, adress, zip code and city) to the database.

should I in my order model/table use a new set of fields - first name, last name, adress, zip code, city or should I create a relationship between my asp_Membershihp table and my Orders table?

Also, If i have dupe data, once a users asks for his account to be removed I wont have any orphan rows in my Orders table if I use the first method.

so, which is best, to have the user data, first name, last name, adress, zipcode, city in only one table and create a relationship between aspnet_Membership table and Orders table OR create the dupe fields in my Orders table with no relationship to the aspnet_Membership table? Pros cons?

Thanks!

/P

Comment: Would not the second approach (dupe data, no relationship) cause you to lose tracking between Clients and Orders?

Comment: Yes it would. Actually you gave me an idea. Maybe the preferred way is to go with both dupe data AND a relationship? Pros? Cons?

Comment: Relationships are the best way to go, duplication of data leads to having to remember to update it mulitple places.  I would recommend that you have a users table for authentication, customer table for name/address/etc with a FK back to a user (userId), and an order table that has a FK back to a customer.  If someone deletes their account, mark the customer as inactive.  You never lose data, there is no duplication and everything should be normalized.

Comment: @Tommy, true as a general rule, but those are orders, if you change a Customer data you should not change the billing data for that past order anyway, am i right?

Comment: @M.Ang that is correct. I wouldnt want to change billing data for past orders.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, i would rather have the relationship.

Also being the data you are storing Orders (i assume at least, from the name :)) i would maintain a separate set of data on the Order, so one would optionally be able to specify different billing/shipping data than it's Identity on the site.

Another valid reason for duplicate at least some data on the Order table is to have all the necessary data relevant to an Order in the table, thus avoiding problems if the Client request his data to be deleted, and maintain the original values for that data on the order if the customer data were to change in time.

If you are able to, though, you should not actually delete User data, but have a field in which you specify if the User isActive or isDeleted.